# Find the error (cumulative function of abs.cont. random variable)

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Let $X$ be an abs. cont. random variable. Then, for $k \in \mathbb{R}$, $prob(X \leqslant k \leqslant \alpha X)=prob (X\leqslant k)-prob(X\leqslant \frac{k}{\alpha})$. I cannot understeand why it doesn't hold $prob(X \leqslant k \leqslant \alpha X)=prob(X\geqslant \frac{k}{\alpha})-prob (X\leqslant k)=1-prob(X\leqslant \frac{k}{\alpha})-prob (X\leqslant k)$.

Thansk.

KB

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the assertion looks a little odd, but it is correct. Using your analysis, we have that
$$\Pr(X\le k\le \alpha X)=\Pr\left(X\ge \frac{k}{\alpha}\right)-\Pr(k\le X).$$
(Note the correction in the second term.) The first term on the right is then $1-\Pr(X\le \frac{k}{\alpha})$ and the second term is $1-\Pr(k\ge x)$.  Subtract and note the cancellation.

**Remark:** Another approach is to make the two inequalities look more "normal."  The first says that $X\le k$. The second says (for positive $\alpha$), that $\frac{k}{\alpha}\le X$. Together they say that
$$\frac{k}{\alpha}\le X\le k,$$
and now the expression given in the post is clearly correct.